# Actualizar página después de eliminar

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Buenas mi problema es ahora uno nuevo ya he llegado hasta donde mi conocimiento da y vengo por ayuda se daran cuenta que he publicado varias preguntas,
Tengo una lista de Servicios Prestados en cada Submenú según el Área (Aplicaciones ,Comunicaciones, ...), que es una sola vista html y según el submenu seleccionado me envia la lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al dar eliminar en uno de los servicios prestados me muestra el modal 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al Eliminar me hace todo pero me sale esto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

, trate de hacer un render , HttpResponce y otros pero no me funcionan, siempre me dejan la url del eliminar y no me recarga la misma url

```
  def Delete_ServPrest(request, pk):
       data = dict()
       servicioPrest = get_object_or_404(ServPrestadoAEmpres, pk=pk)
       if request.method == 'POST':
    servicioPrest.delete()
 else:
      form = FormSerPrest(instance=servicioPrest)
      context = {'form': form}
      data['html_form'] = render_to_string('templates_Delete/delete_ServPrest.html', context, request=request)

  return JsonResponse(data)
```

```js
   var EliminarServPrest = function () {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                location.reload(true);
                $("#modal-serviciosP").modal("hide");

            }
        });
        return false;
    };
   $("#modal-servicios").on("submit", ".delete_servicioP_form", EliminarServPrest);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form" action="{% url 'eicma:delete_ServPrest' form.instance.pk %}" method="post" class="form-horizontal delete_servicioP_form" name="delete_servicioP_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <h3>Eliminar Servicio Prestado</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body ">

        <div class="panel panel-default ">
            <div class="panel-body 2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="areaSP" class="control-label">Está seguro que desea eliminar el Servicio Prestado a: <strong>{{form.instance.clienteSP}}</strong></label>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary Eliminar" name="submit" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>


</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pudieras intentar con un `window.location = "/la/url/que/quiero/"` al momento de procesar la respuesta exitosa de tu petición ajax

Donde la `/la/url/que/quiero/` la pudieras definir de varias formas

**1. con el template tag `url`**

`window.location = "{%  url 'nombre_de_la_url' %}"`

**Definiendola en la respuesta de tu view**

Pudieras definirla como parte de la data que retornas, luego de eliminar, de esta forma

```
# views.py
data["url"] = reverse("nombre_de_la_url")
```

Y la procesas en tu respuesta ajax

```
success: function (response) {
        $("#modal-serviciosP").modal("hide");
        window.location =  response.url;
}
```

espero sea de ayuda

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con esta respuesta:

Comment: @Reynald0 muchas gracias, pudieras puntearla....

Comment: Y antes de data["url"] = reverse("nombre_de_la_url") como pondria para obtener la url de donde viene la petición, es que ese eliminar es para 4 url diferentes

Comment: El objeto request tiene algunos métodos y propiedades que te pudieran ayudar a saber desde donde se hace la petición, por ejemplo `request.get_host()` o los datos de `request.META` experimenta con ellos, y si tienes alguna duda puntual abre otra pregunta

Comment: Hola hice lo que me dijeron y me muestra el json con la url no me redirecciona, trate con esta otra forma y tampoco window.location.href =  respose.url;

Comment: @AntonioVeliz pudieras chequear que estes devolviendo la url correcta?

Comment: bueno yo hice lo que me dijeron por aki data["url"] = reverse("nombre_de_la_url") y cuando me muestra el json es la url correcta, y puse dentro del success un console.long(respose.url) para ver lo que me devuelve y no me muestra nada

Comment: @AntonioVeliz puedes probar en la consola de tu navegador probando la sentencia, asegurate de estar utilizando los nombres correctos en los atributos de la respuesta

Comment: En la url tengo lo tengo asi url(r'^eliminar/$', Delete_ServPrest, name='eliminar'), esta url son de otro proyecto aparte que las incuyo lo cual me quedaria asi cuando asigno la url :  data["url"] = reverse("proyect:eliminar") cuando me devuelve en la vista no hace nada se mantiene la url de eliminar y lo que me muestra es el json que retorno la funcion que tiene incluida la url {' url':'proyect/lista_ServP ' }

Comment: @AntonioVeliz son ides mías o el key `url` tiene un espacio al inicio, asegurate bien de estar llamando correctamente al key que devuelve el response

Comment: @AngelF ya lo resolvi era un error mio al llamar el modal graicas, que posibilidades hay de que  me ayudes con la pregunta Editar datos en tabla dinámica que tengo aqui saludos

Comment: @AntonioVeliz excelente que resolviste, bueno crea la pregunta y déjame por comentario el enlace, si está a mi alcance con mucho gusto te ayudo

Comment: @AngelF este es el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135459/editar-datos-en-tabla-din%c3%a1mica cualquier cosa que no entiendas me dices